# Entity Framework Core - Updating Nested Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given these two classes:

```
public class Device {
   public int DeviceId { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set;}
}

public class DeviceType {
   public int DeviceTypeId { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

And assuming I get Device from database the following way:

```
var device = context.Devices.Include(d => d.DeviceType).FirstOrDefault();
```

How would I update DeviceType for selected device?

I've been trying the following way:

```
device.DeviceType = new DeviceType { DeviceTypeId = 1 };
context.SaveChanges();
```

However that does not work and give me the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'DeviceType' 
cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{DeviceTypeId: 1}' 
is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one 
entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

**EDIT** 
Works the following way

```
context.Entry<Device>(device).Property<int?>("DeviceTypeId").CurrentValue = 1;
```

But it's not that elegant. I wonder if there is better way.

Comment: Try find device index using LINQ. If index isn't found then do assign.

Comment: Put `DeviceTypeId` in `Device` as a foreign key property.